# Drone slaves provided by CoreOs

Tags: coreos, drone.io, fleet

I have a drone host and a CoreOS cluster with fleet.
The drone now have only unix:///var/run/docker.sock in the nodes menu.
As I understand, I could add other docker nodes defined by docker URLs and certificates. However once I have a CoreOS cluster, it seems logical to use that as the provider of the slaves. I am looking for a solution where

(1)I don't have to configure the nodes whenever the CoreOS cluster configration changes, and

(2) provides correct resource management.

I could think of the following solutions:

- Expose docker uris in the CoreOS cluster nodes, and configure all of them directly in drone. In this case I would have follow CoreOs cluster changes manually. Resource management would probably conflict with that of fleet.
- Expose docker uris in the CoreOS cluster nodes, and provide a DNS round-robin based access. Seems to be a terrible way of resource management, and would most probably conflict with feet.
- Install Swarm on the CoreOs nodes. Resource management would probably conflict with that of fleet.
- Have fleet or RKT expose a docker uri, and fleet/RKT would decide on which node the container runs on. The problem is that I could not find any way to do this.
- Have drone.io use fleet or RKT. Same problem. Is it possible?

Is there any way to provide solutions for all of my requirements with drone.io and CoreOs?

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand, I could add other docker nodes defined by docker URLs
>   and certificates. However once I have a CoreOS cluster, it seems
>   logical to use that as the provider of the slaves.

The newest version of drone supports build agents. Build agents are installed per-server and will communicate with the central drone server to pull builds from the queue, execute and send back the results.

```
docker run                                              \
    -e DRONE_SERVER=http://my.drone.server              \
    -e DRONE_SECRET=passcode                            \ 
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/container/path/docker.sock \
    drone/drone:0.5 agent
```

This allows you to add and remove agents on the fly without having to register or manage them at the server level.

I believe this should solve the basic problem you've outlined, although I'm not sure it will provide the level of integration you desire with fleet and coreos. Perhaps a coreos expert can augment my answer.